# Parallelize the psuedo inverse calculation in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, python-xarray

Is there a way to parallelize the calculation of a matrix operation on just two dimensions of a 3D matrix…? 
For example, I want to calculate the psuedo inverse of a (3x2) matrix at each `sig` level of `G` so that the resulting matrix would be (2x3x5) with the `sig` dimension not included in calculating the inverse; the inverse would be just for the `row` and `col` dimensions on each `sig` level.

Ideally, I would like to achieve this in somewhat of a similar fashion below:

```
G = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(3,2,5), dims=['row','col','sig'])

pinvG = xr.apply_ufunc(np.linalg.pinv, G.chunk({'sig':1}),  
                        output_core_dims=[['j','i']], 
#                         input_core_dims=[['sig'],['sig']],
#                         exclude_dims={'sig','sig'},
                        dask='parallelized', 
                        output_dtypes=[float], output_sizes={'j':2,'i':3}).compute()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do what I wanted by using `dask.array.map_blocks`:

```
pinvG = dsar.map_blocks(np.linalg.pinv,G.transpose('sig','row','col').chunk({'sig':1}).data)
```